# Getting a regex to return a number range (e.g. salary) from unstructured text

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to extract salary information from emails and job adverts.

I need a regex that will return the first instance of the range or salary number (I also want to avoid matching phone numbers that might occur later in the string) e.g.

```
"blah blah £500 blah".match(regex)
=> "£500"
"balh blah £500-650 blah".match(regex)
=> "£500-650"
"£50 per hour".match(regex) 
=> "£50" (or "£50 per hour" for an advanced version)
"blah blah £50k blah".match(regex)
=> "£50k"
"bblah blah 50-60k".match(regex)
=> "50-60k"
"blah blah 50000 blahblahblah".match(regex)  
=> "50000"
"blah 50000 - 60000 blablahblah 0207-123-4567".match(regex) 
=> "50000 - 60000"
#"blah 350 to 425 blah".match(regex) 
#=> "350 to 425" Can forget this last one as it's a bit of an edge case
```

I've got this far.

```
/(£|$)?[0-9][0-9]{0,5}[0-9,k]?(-| - | to )?((£|$)?[0-9][0-9]{0,5}[0,5,k]?)?/
```

Or a slightly enhanced:

```
/(£|$)?[0-9][0-9]{0,5}[0-9,k]?(-| - | to )?((£|$)?[0-9][0-9][0,5,k]?)? ?(ph|pw|pa| per|per)? ?(hour|annum|week|month)?/
```

Sort of works but doesn't match the whole substring number range, there seems to be lots of matches of the individual pieces.

e.g.

```
"bblah blah 50-60k".match(regex)
=> #<MatchData "50-60k" 1:nil 2:"-" 3:"60k" 4:nil>
```

I want it to just say

```
"50-60k"
```

What am I missing (and is there a more elegant way to do this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concluded it would be best to do this in two steps. First, let's remove phone numbers:

```
r0 = /
     \d+        # Match one or more digits
     (?:        # Begin a non-capture group
       \s*\-\s* # Match a hypen optionally surrounded with spaces
       \d+      # Match one or more digits
     ){2}       # Close non-capture and perform it twice
    /x          # Extended/free-spacing mode

arr0 = ["blah blah £500 blah",
        "balh blah £500-650 blah",
        "£50 per hour",
        "blah blah £50k blah",
        "bblah blah 50-60k",
        "blah blah 50000 blahblahblah",
        "blah 50000 - £60000 blablahblah 0207-123-4567",
        "bblah blah 50k-£60k"
       ]

arr1 = arr0.map { |str| str.gsub(r0,'') }
  #=> ["blah blah £500 blah",
  #    "balh blah £500-650 blah",
  #    "£50 per hour",
  #    "blah blah £50k blah",
  #    "bblah blah 50-60k",
  #    "blah blah 50000 blahblahblah",
  #    "blah 50000 - £60000 blablahblah ",
  #    "bblah blah 50k-£60k"]
```

I've assumed that all phone numbers are three strings of digits separated by hyphens that are optionally surrounded with spaces. If that assumption is not correct you would of course have to modify `r0` as appropriate.

Now extract the values desired from the elements of `arr1`:

```
r1 = /
     £?         # Optionally begin with a pound sign
     \d+k?      # Match one or more digits optionally followed by k
     (?:        # Begin non-capture group
       \s*\-\s* # Match a hypen optionally surrounded with spaces
       \d+k?    # Match one or more digits optionally followed by k
     )?         # End non-capture group and make the match optional
     \b         # word break
     /x         # Extended/free-spacing mode

arr1.map { |s| s[r1] }
  #=> ["£500", "£500-650", "£50", "£50k", "50-60k", "50000", "50000", "50k"]
```

Comment: That is looking like it's getting somewhere, but I've clarified the question a little by editing. Those strings with => are me trying to indicate the string at the start with the requried output after the arrow.... Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: I'll also clarify that sometimes it's just a number, other times it's a range of numbers. The example I'm looking at is job information. Sometimes people will list the salary as £50k. sometimes they'll list it as £50000-60000. In these cases either the single number or the range is important.

Comment: Will they ever enter  £50000 - £60000?  £50000 is not bad. but wouldn't it be hard to get by on "£500-650", especially in central London?

Comment: Not if they're paying that (£500-650) per day (as they would be in this case...)

Comment: Keiran, don't forget the first sentence of my comment (where I asked if both ends of a range could begin with '£').

Comment: Sorry. Yes they will enter that. Not as commonly as £50000-60000 or even £50-60000 / £50-60k. 
They'll definitely write things like £500 - £650 (often it's being filled by a 'mail-merge', where if a min and ma value exists, it will put them in that format).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have a small query that how can I extract the amount from the string which is something like "20k per month to 1.5L per month"

Comment: @Maniraj, if I understand your question correctly, change `r1` to `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?k per month to \d+(?:\.\d+)?L per month/`. This also matches `"20.2k per month to 2L per month"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new update.

```
((?:£)\d{1,}\-(?:\d{1,}(?:\-|\w))|\d{1,} - \d{1,}|\d{1,} to \d{1,}|(?<=\s)\d{1,}\-\d{1,}(?:k|(?=\s))|(?:£)\d{1,}(?:\w)|(?<=\s)\d{1,}(?=\s))
```

This should work for all scenarios.

Here is one that includes the "per hour"

```
((?:£)\d{1,}\-(?:\d{1,}(?:\-|\w))|\d{1,} - \d{1,}|\d{1,} to \d{1,}|(?<=\s)\d{1,}\-\d{1,}(?:k|(?=\s))|(?:£)\d{1,}(?:\w| per hour)|(?<=\s)\d{1,}(?=\s))
```

Comment: That is pretty elegant. Doesn't work with the 50000-60000 example though. i.e. I'm trying to match the whole range (since, interestingly, it's the latter value - 60000 - that's most important, and I want the range to be a string value "50000 - 60000"). But I don't want to match later examples as I'll run the risk of running into things which look a bit like numbers but aren't really what I'm after... e.g. if the phone number in an email starts 800 I'd end up in trouble if I ignore whether or not it was 'connected' to the first number I find.

Comment: Have clarified above as I think the question wasn't clear.

Comment: Gotcha - I need to get a few things done for work and then Ill come back with a new solution. Give me an hour or so... In the mean time, could you post the lines with actual (more or less) examples. It will help me debug.

Comment: It's a bit tricky to do that as the strings can be quite long (it's an entire email message including the description, for example)

Comment: "Senior PHP Developer London circa £50000 required" Would be an example... 
Or "Hi Bob, I'm looking to hire a Programme Manager.... rate: £500-750 per day......"